# ORA-00911: invalid character - Using XMLType

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype

I have been working with Oracle XML DB of version 11gR2.  I have created a XML table with column as XMLType(Binary XMLType).

**Question 1:**
When I insert a XML document, all the single quotes in the attributes list gets converted to double quotes automatically.  How can I get rid of this?  Because I have to reprocess the entire XML document when I have to fetch it.

**Question 2:**
When I tried to retrieve I have used function getclobval().  This is working well with SQLPLUS and SQL Developer.  However when I run this query through OCI, I am getting the error "ORA-00911: invalid character"

Can anyone help me on the above two questions?

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
Have a look on Oracle support at bug 9871299: LOSS OF UNESCAPING WITH XMLTABLE

This bug was introduced in 11.2.0.1.

Comment: Thank you for your quick update, Rene...  This solves one of my biggest bottleneck.